# Decouple business logic from a kafka consumer

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

I am implementing a kafka consumer using spring kafka and its @KafkaListener annotation on a void method

I essentially need to do some transformation and then publish the message back out to the topic

However I want to create a construct so I don't publish to a topic inside the consumer. I want to delegate the payload to another class and then invoke the publisher within the delegated class there

Here is an example

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "ID", topics = "REQUEST-TOPIC")
    public void getPartArrangementViaPartRoutingArrangement(@Payload String content) {
        

        try {

            // omitted code implementation for mapping and transformation
            String partConfigIdsToSend = "Transformed" + content;
            
            // send a message on another topic directly inside the consumer, is there a way we can delegate this into another class
            publisher.sendPartConfigs(partConfigIdsToSend);


        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Like to delegate the producer into another class and not invoke directly inside the consumer

Comment: I don't see any problems with your logic. So, what is wrong with having that `publisher` business service which is going to call `KafkaTemplate.send()` ?

Comment: I guess I was curious to know how you could delegate the payload to another service class and invoke the method over there. Just to make the separations very clear and keep the consumer only consuming the message and doing the transformation

Comment: The way you have it no is OK. There is also a feature via `@SendTo` which is going to use a return of this `@KafkaListener` as a body for record to produce for the topic. But that one is mostly designed for replies: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#annotation-send-to